# jQuery.ScrollTo plugin issue when hiding/showing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I'm using [Arial Flesler's ScrollTo plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) to slide "sections" of a page horizontally.

In this case, I don't want to slide through all sections. I'd like my sections to slide from one to another without showing the other sections inbetween.

I've set up a jsFiddle to describe it more precisely: http://jsfiddle.net/PWj4B/2/

What I'm doing is hiding all sections but the currently visible one, showing the section corresponding to the anchor I clicked and then scrolling to that section.

For some reason, the sliding doesn't work when I try to slide to the same direction more than once. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is happening because the `div` appears and immediately replaces the position of the current `div`. (When it's to the right of the current div, your lower div is pushed left. When it's to the left of your current div, the higher div is pushed right.)

This plugin isn't meant to do what you're asking of it, I don't think.

How about something like... http://jsfiddle.net/PWj4B/4/

It gives absolute position to your slides and places your target slide to either the left or right of the mask. Then it animates both the current slide and the target slide together.

Comment: Yeah, I realized what I was doing wrong just a few minutes before seeing your answer. :P
Anyway, thanks a lot for making it clear. In my case, I'd need the slides not to have absolute position, because they have varied heights, but I guess that's something that could be worked out.

Answer (score 0):

As **stuard** pointed out, the `div`s were being pushed aside, so I realized I could simply scroll to the current `div` without delay and then scroll to the target `div`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/PWj4B/5/